# how to make function and call the function in ajax call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do I make this:

```
$('.projects').hover(function(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true).fadeToggle(1000).html('test');
});
```

into a function, and then call it in a ajax call?

```
//  Check to ensure that a link with href == hash is on the page  
if ($('a[href="' + hash + '"]').length) {
    //  Load the page.
    var toLoad = hash + '.php #main-content';
    $('#main-content').load(toLoad);
}
$('nav ul li a').click(function () {
    var goingTo = $(this).attr('href');
    goingTo = goingTo.substring(goingTo.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    if (window.location.hash.substring(1) === goingTo) return false;
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href') + ' #main-content',
        $content = $('#main-content'),
        $loadimg = $('#load');
    $content.fadeOut('fast', loadContent);
    $loadimg.remove();
    $content.append('<span id="load"></span>');
    $loadimg.fadeIn('slow');
    window.location.hash = goingTo;

    function loadContent() {
        $content.load(toLoad, '', showNewContent)
    }

    function showNewContent() {
        $content.fadeIn('fast', hideLoader, log);
    }

    function hideLoader() {
        $loadimg.fadeOut('fast');
    }
    return false;
});
```

my functions

```
$('.projects dl').find('dd').hide();

  function fadeBox(){
    $('#def-box').stop(true, true)
      .fadeToggle(1000)
      .html('test');
  }

  $('.projects').hover(function(){ 
    fadeBox();
    });
  function descBox(){
    $('.projects dl').find('dd').hide();
    var $data = $(this)
      .next('dd')
      .html();
    $('#def-box').html($data);
  }

  $('.projects dl dt').hover(function(){
     descBox();
    });
```

and ajax

```
function showNewContent() {
        fadeBox();
        descBox();
        $content.fadeIn('fast',hideLoader);  
    }
```

Also this isn't working. Its suppose to get the hidden `dd` element an place it in `#def-box` when its hovered when the `dt` is hovered.

```
function descBox(){
    $('.projects dl').find('dd').hide();
    var $data = $(this)
      .next('dd')
      .html('test');
    $('#def-box').html($data);
 }
```

Also the `dd` elements are hidden if I click to anotherpage, but on load... `http://example.co/#home` the `dd` isn't hidden no more.

Comment: Making it a function is easy, surround it with `function <name>(){` and `}`. but now sure I understand what you mean by call it with AJAX--have it run when AJAX returns?

Answer (score 1):

```
  // create the function
function myfunc(){
    $defBox.stop(true, true).fadeToggle(1000).html('test');
}

  // use it as the handler
$('.projects').hover( myfunc );

  // call it in the showNewContent function
function showNewContent() {
    myfunc();
    $content.fadeIn('fast',hideLoader, log);  
}
```

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for helping again. I put the function in showNewContent() but  doesn't seem to work. How can I find out if its  being called? console.log()? alert?

Comment: @Trippy: Yeah, you can put console.logs in the functions to see where it is breaking down.

Comment: Hey patrick! after 2 weeks of searching,, you finally helped me out! everything is kinda working now! But some of it doesn't work, look at the question I edited and tell me if what I'm doing is right

Comment: @Trippy: Everything looks alright, though for your hovers you can simply do `$('.projects').hover(fadeBox);`, which is a little more efficient than wrapping the function call in another function. What part of it isn't working for you?

Comment: @Trippy: Sure. Being global, everything everywhere has access to them. But don't use them (if you're talking about actual globals).

Comment: Well I mean .... after dom is ready, set variables so both functions can use this.

Comment: @Trippy: In your `descBox` function, the keyword `this` is referring to the `window` if you're calling it like you are. If you do `$('.projects dl dt').hover(descBox);` then `this` will refer to  the `dt` getting hovered. If you call it like `descBox()` in the AJAX callback, you'll have the same issue with `this`.

Comment: So what should I do? Change this to what I am referring too?

Comment: @Trippy: You mean from the AJAX callback? In order to set the proper value of `this` when you call it from there, you can use the `.call()` method, and give it an argument that represents whatever you want `this` to mean in the function. So `descBox.call( someElement )`. Then `this` in `descBox` will refer to whatever element you passed to `.call()`.

Comment: ...another option would be to select some element and call `.mouseenter()`, as in `$('someSelector').eq(0).mouseenter()` where the selector matches an element that has the `descBox` function as the `hover` handler. Remember to change the hover handler as I described above to `$('.projects dl dt').hover(descBox);`

Comment: So i'm referring to .projects dl so descBox.call('.projects dl')? And where would I put this? And thank you for your help Patrick I wish I could give you a million points right now.

Comment: @Trippy: If you're talking about the callback to the AJAX call, just do `$('.projects dl').mouseenter()` to call the handler. That'll be simplest. Just be aware that it will fire it once for each `dl` it finds.